# difference between pagebookview and normal view

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

what is the difference between PageBookView and Normal view? when do we use PageBookView and Normal View?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A PageBookView simply is used to implement views like the [Outline](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/viewvc.cgi/org.eclipse.ui.views/src/org/eclipse/ui/views/contentoutline/ContentOutline.java?view=markup) view, `org.eclipse.ui.views.contentoutline.ContentOutline`.  It provides the default framework to switch pages based on the incoming active part.

EDIT: A PageBookView is a view that can contain multiple pages, but it only shows one page at a time.  In this context, a page is a class implementing `org.eclipse.ui.part.IPageBookViewPage`.  It can create a `Control` and can interact with the framework, like providing view tool items.

The [Console](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/viewvc.cgi/org.eclipse.ui.console/src/org/eclipse/ui/internal/console/ConsoleView.java?view=markup) view, `org.eclipse.ui.internal.console.ConsoleView` is an example that uses the PageBookView to manage pages, but doesn't switch console pages on part activation.  Instead it offers a dropdown of pages that the user can switch to.

PW

Comment: Did not understand properly. PageBookView gives layout like Book. Is that correct?